# Is there library that allows to switch between local file storage and Amazon S3 in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have application that saves all uploaded files to S3. But sometimes I need save data to local file storage.

Is there some library that could do something like this:

```
var storage = new Storage(local);
storage.save(hello.mp3);
```

or

```
var storage = new Storage(s3);
storage.save(hello.mp3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just looking at Factory pattern ?

```
var Storage = function (type) {
    if (type === "local") return new LocalStorage();
    if (type === "s3") return new S3Storage();
}
```

of course, LocalStorage and S3Storage must share the same method save()